# Выделение подстроки из строки

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <сstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char tmpstr[255], tmpcmpstr [16];
    FILE *regstream;
    regstream = fopen("dbase.txt", "r+");
    while (!feof(regstream))
    {
        fgets (tmpstr, 255, regstream);//считываем строку поностью
        if (tmpstr[0] == 'c')
        {
            strncpy(tmpcmpstr, tmpstr + 2, 16); //считывание подстроки
            cout<<tmpcmpstr<<"\n\n\n"; //вывод подстроки. происходит хрень
        }
    }
    fclose(regstream);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Программа должна из строк выделять только число
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первые 16 символов выводятся правильно, а дальше идет что-то непонятное.
ВОПРОС: откуда это берется и в чем ошибка?

Файл dbase.txt http://www.mediafire.com/view/1akymarbxaofnxb/dbase.txt

Comment: Так а зачем здесь тег [C++]? Предполагается, что можно вообще все вышенаписанное выкинуть нафиг и переписать через `std::string`?

Comment: Да, ответы принимаются как для С так и для С++, а лучше - все вместе.

Answer (score 3):

tmpcmpstr у вас 16 байт. Вы в нее пишете 16 байт через strncpy(), то есть затираете нулевой байт в tmpcmpstr[15] (если бы он там был по причине инициализации). Функция печати не встречает нулевого байта и продолжает читать и выводить на экран трэш до тех пор, пока не встретит нулевой байт.

Comment: поменял на tmpcmpstr[50] - http://i.imgur.com/in1NUry.png

Comment: Вы копируете не более 16 байт. Сама строка содержит 16 цифр. Финальный ноль НЕ КОПИРУЕТСЯ.

Comment: что тогда сделать, чтобы был символ конца строки?

Comment: Если у вас буфер в 50 байт - копируйте туда не более 50 байт и все будет хорошо, пока строка будет менее 50 байт.

Comment: @neko69, Символы конца строки у вас печатаются. Что бы не было мусора, можете например расширить масив tmpcmpstr до 17 байт, и сразу устанавливать последний байт в 0. Хотя в общем-то использовать strncpy для ваших целей не очень-то хорошо - строки файла у вас являются "пользовательским вводом", соответственно доверять ему нельзя, и нужно заранее проверять и обрабатывать все возможные отхождения от нормы.

Comment: strncpy не позволит скопировать больше чем указано и для пользовательского ввода это не так и плохо, особенно если в конце буфера нулевой байт и strncpy его не может затереть.

Comment: @sergey-rufanov Добавил tmpcmpstr[16] = '\0'; и все заработало. А чем лучше заменить strncpy ?

Comment: С какой целью менять?

Comment: Чтобы из " использовать strncpy для ваших целей не очень-то хорошо" стало очень хорошо

Comment: Я не считаю strncpy чем-то плохим, особенно если его использовать грамотно.

Comment: @neko69, в С++ для таких задач обычно используют метод `string::substr`. Ну а в обычном С(если бы ввод был не пользовательским, а провереным) скорее бы просто вывели `tmpstr + 2`, без всяких strncpy, благо fgets даёт на выходе строки с нормальным нулевым байтом в конце

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, как было правильно замечено, для хранения сишной строки длины `16` нужен буфер размера как минимум `17`.

Во-вторых, функция `strncpy` не предназначена для "выделения подстроки из строки" и применять ее для этой цели не стоит. Это бессмысленно. Если ваша платформа не предоставляет `strlcpy` (которая, к сожалению, не входит в стандарт), то пользуйтесь обыкновенной `memcpy` для собственно копирования и не забывайте добавлять нулевой терминатор в конце

```
char tmpcmpstr[17];
...

memcpy(tmpcmpstr, tmpstr + 2, 16);
tmpcmpstr[16] = '\0';
```

И вообще, если вы пишете С-код, то настоятельно рекомендуется либо убедиться в наличии функции `strlcpy` на вашей платформе, либо (если таковая отсутствует) написать ее самостоятельно. И в дальнейшем пользоваться именно ей.

В-третьих, не мешало бы еще определиться с тем, что делать если входная строка недостаточно длинна для выполнения такого копирования. Это уже у вас надо спрашивать.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишите на языке C++, то и используйте средства именно этого языка, а не C. Нет никакой необходимости использовать в данном случае функции C, когда есть более развитые и надежные функции C++.

Более того вы зачем-то включили заголовок `<string>` в свою программу, но ни одно объявление из этого заголовка не используете.

Строковые функции C, к которым вы обращаетесь в программе, на самом деле объявлены в заголовке `<cstring>`.

Ваша программа может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in( "dbase.txt" );
    std::string record;

    while ( std::getline( in, record ) )
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );
        std::string field;

        if ( is >> field && field == "c" && is >> field )
        {
            std::cout << field << std::endl;
        }
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Я не проверял ее работу, так как у меня нет файла с вашими данными, но по крайней мере она успешно компилируется. Вы можете ее использовать как основу для написания своей именно C++ программы, а не нечто непонятное на чем написанное.